# Mongodb Index not used in case of $or query

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I have added created a collection `first` and created index;

```
db.first.createIndex({a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1, f:1});
```

then inserted data

```
db.first.insert({a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6});
db.first.insert({a:1, b:6});
```

When making queries like

```
db.first.find({f: 6, a:1, c:3}).sort({b: -1}).explain();
```

indexes are used (`IXSCAN`)

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "myproject.first",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "c" : {
                        "$eq" : 3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "f" : {
                        "$eq" : 6
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "a" : 1,
                    "b" : 1,
                    "c" : 1,
                    "d" : 1,
                    "e" : 1,
                    "f" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_1_d_1_e_1_f_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "a" : [ ],
                    "b" : [ ],
                    "c" : [ ],
                    "d" : [ ],
                    "e" : [ ],
                    "f" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "backward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "a" : [
                        "[1.0, 1.0]"
                    ],
                    "b" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "c" : [
                        "[3.0, 3.0]"
                    ],
                    "d" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "e" : [
                        "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                    ],
                    "f" : [
                        "[6.0, 6.0]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "SORT",
                "sortPattern" : {
                    "b" : -1
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                    "inputStage" : {
                        "stage" : "FETCH",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [
                                {
                                    "c" : {
                                        "$eq" : 3
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "f" : {
                                        "$eq" : 6
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                            "keyPattern" : {
                                "a" : 1
                            },
                            "indexName" : "a_1",
                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                                "a" : [ ]
                            },
                            "isUnique" : false,
                            "isSparse" : false,
                            "isPartial" : false,
                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                            "direction" : "forward",
                            "indexBounds" : {
                                "a" : [
                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.4",
        "gitVersion" : "d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but when I use or query

```
db.first.find({ $or: [{f: 6}, {a:1}]}).explain();
```

index is not used instead columns are scanned (`COLLSCAN`)

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "myproject.first",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "f" : {
                        "$eq" : 6
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "$or" : [
                        {
                            "a" : {
                                "$eq" : 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "f" : {
                                "$eq" : 6
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "direction" : "forward"
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Manishs-MacBook-Pro.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.6.4",
        "gitVersion" : "d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have a compound index is the cause for indexes not being used with `$or`.

> When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either
>   performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by
>   indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use
>   indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or
>   expression must be supported by indexes. Otherwise, MongoDB will
>   perform a collection scan.
>
> When using indexes with $or queries, each clause of an $or can use its
>   own index. Consider the following query:
>
> ```
> db.inventory.find( { $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] } )
> ```
>
> To support this query, rather than a compound index, you would create
>   one index on quantity and another index on price:
>
> ```
> db.inventory.createIndex( { quantity: 1 } )
> db.inventory.createIndex( { price: 1 } )
> ```

[$or Clauses and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes)

---

So just by adding individual indexing for fields `f` and `a` like;

```
db.first.createIndex({a:1});
db.first.createIndex({f:1});
```

will make your

```
db.first.find({ $or: [{f: 6}, {a:1}]})
```

query to use indexing.

Comment: Thanx for the quick response. or query is on keys `f` and `a` and both of these keys are in the index `{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4, e:5, f:6}` so why is it still not using index?

Comment: @FastTurtle because it is a compound index, and for an `$or` operation to use indexing, it needs individual indexes on the targeted fields, since each should be evaluated independently from other fields. Check my updated answer, see the `createIndex` calls I suggest at the end there

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is, you've created a compound index on {a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1, f:1} fields but you're not following the order of the index. So your queries should contain all the fields in the same order that you've constructed your index. Since the field 'f' is in the tail end of the index, your queries will not utilize or even identify it

Your queries:

```
db.first.find({f: 6, a:1, c:3}).sort({b: -1})
db.first.find({ $or: [{f: 6}, {a:1}]})
```

To make both your above queries use the index, you should build the compound index as below:

```
db.first.createIndex({ f:1, a:1, b:1, c:1 })
```

OR: you can build individual indexes on all fields and use it in any order in your query.

Remember: If you're building compound index, make sure to follow the Equality, Sort and Range order

Comment: Any reason `db.first.find({f: 6, a:1, c:3}).sort({b: -1})` hits the index but not `db.first.find({ $or: [{f: 6}, {a:1}]})`

Comment: Because your 2nd query is using $or operator, which must either have individual indexes on the fields or you build compound index in the right order