# How to create indexes in Mongo when having a query with AND's and OR's together?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've read that for only OR queries like:

```
find($or [{field1:a}, {field2:b}])
```

an index for each field shall be created (simple or compound with the fields as prefix).
For AND queries like:

```
find(field1:a, field2:b)
```

a compound index shall be created to cover it throughly.
But what to do when a query has AND's and OR's together?

```
find($or[field1:a, field2:b], field3:c, field4:d)
```

What are all of the indexes to be created in this case?

MongoDB 4.4.6

Comment: If you reorganize the query as `find({$or:[{field1:a, field3:c, field4:d}, {field2:b, field3:c, field4:d}]})`  the 2 indexes you need should become apparent.

Comment: @Joe as I understood, the important thing is that the indexes must have, as prefix, each field of the OR filter, REGARDLESS cardinality, right? Even if field3 as the most cardinality among all fields, indexes must start with the OR fields

Comment: I've never heard of lumping the or'd fields together like that.  I was pointing out that `(A and B and (C or D))` is logically equivalent to `((A and B and C) or (A and B and D))`, so if you create indexes on A+B+C and A+B+D, both branches of the query can be properly serviced by an index.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-is-mongodb-not-taking-an-existing-unique-compound-index-for-an-or-query/103229

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621226/mongodb-index-not-used-in-case-of-or-query

Comment: In both of those example there were only 2 fields being queried with `$or`, so they required single-field indexes or for those fields to be the prefix of an index.  In this case you have 4 fields, effectively 2 branches to the `$or`, which each branch querying 3 fields.  The important point is that each branch of the `$or` must be supported by an index in order to avoid a collection scan.

Comment: but if u have a AND (b OR c), and create indexes like (a, b), (a,c), actually the OR clauses are NOT supported by the indexes, cause to be supported they must be prefixes of the indexes. That's what I understood. I also tried it, by creating both indexes (a,b) and (b,a), and the query uses (b,a). In the forum I linked to you, for queries like OR(a,b) without AND, they created the index (a,b), which is supporting a but not b, because b wants its index with b as prefix, otherwise index (a,b) would be enough. Does it make sense?

Comment: For the execution that used (b,a) it also considered the index on (a,b), right? If you run that query using explain and the "allPlansExecution" option you will be able to compare the performance of each index. Basically, rewrite the query so it is a top-level $or, and then for each branch, create the index that you would use if that branch were the entire query. When each branch is serviced like that, the mongodb query planner will use indexes to support the $or

Comment: Just to be sure, I tested `.find({a:5, $or:[ {b:5}, {c:5} ]})` in MongoDB 4.4.10, it actually did use the indexes on `{a:1, b:1}` and `{a:1, c:1}`.

Comment: I guess it also depends on db's size. I have a db with millions and millions of documents, with 40+ indexes. Sometimes it decides that some indexes are better than others.Sometimes it uses a compound index with just one field from the query's filter and the other ones are totally random, instead of an index which covers almost all of the query. I still don't comprehend this thing perfectly  but  that's what I saw recently, after a large use of mongo. It would be fun trying deleting (a,b) index , replacing it with (b,a) index and see if something changes (docsExamined, millis)

Comment: or hinting (b,a) index

Comment: If there is no cached plan, the mongod will run a short test to see which index performs best.  If you run the query using `explain` with the "allPlansExecution" option, it will show you the results of that that testing

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:  You probably do not need a compound index here but rather individual field indexes on the highest cardinality, most performance-demanding queries.

Compound indexes are very useful when your AND pattern is predictably hierarchical.  If a compound index is created on fields A,B,C then a query on A will be fast,  A,B will be fast, and A,B,C will be (really) fast.  Query on just B cannot use the index, nor B,C, nor C.

If you run your query with `explain(true)` and examine the output, you will see that multiple indexes can be used for *both* `$or` and `$and` types of queries.